# What happens after death?

Tags: support, feature-request, policy, user-accounts, community-user

What will happen with my SE account after my death? Is there something that eg. warn foture users not to try contact with me, because I'm dead? Would my account be deleted for preserving servers memory? Could my family make something memorial with this account?

What other meta problems are generated by death?

Comment: Covered on the mother meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38742/. The short answer is "nothing, you'll just stop contributing".

Comment: @dmckee maybe you won't contribute anything with *that* attitude